# WP_Query array key / value pairs?

Tags: wp-query

I have a WP_Query like this.

```
    <?php
        $quote_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'category_name' => 'quote',
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        );

        $quote  = new WP_Query($quote_args);

        if($quote->have_posts()):
            while($quote->have_posts()):
                $quote->the_post();
    ?>
    <div id="testimonialWrap">  
        <p class="testimonial">
            <?php the_content_rss(); ?>
            <span><?php echo the_title(); ?></span>
            <em></em>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>
```

It just randomly selects posts that are quotes.

My questions is the $quote_args array has a group of key / value pairs: ('post_type' => 'post')

Is there a list of the keys that can be used here. Is there a name for these key / value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a list of the keys that can be used here. Is there a name for
>   these key / value pairs.

[The "list" is in the Codex on the `WP_Query` page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) or you can [just check the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/query.php#L831).

I don't know what kind of "name" you are looking for. Other that "key/value" I'd call them "arguments" or "parameters" (as does the Codex). I really don't understand that part of the question.

Comment: I was going to call them arguments - this is what I was looking for. http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/

Comment: The [WP_Query link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) provided by [s_ha_dum](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21376/s-ha-dum)'s answer has more people looking at it and keeping it updated than Bill's code. Bill's a great person, but ...